# How to import a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble importing a text file into a dictionary in Python.

I have a Python file which currently looks like this:

```
Dictionary = {}

with open("File.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
      (key, val) = line.split()
      Dictionary[int(key)] = val
```

within the text file (File) is text like this:

```
j ^

m +

d !
```

I need to import the text from this file so that the dictionary reads this in and I can then use it later in my program to change letters to symbols and symbols to letters.

Comment: Converting `j`, `m `and `d` to integers is not going to work.

Comment: not converting j, m and d to integers, changing them to symbols

Comment: Please don't name your variables w/upper-case names.  See the [python style](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) guide for more info.

Comment: Drop the int() call and it should work fine.

Comment: @Chopster0123 Perhaps you wanted to use `ord()` rather than `int()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I know what program you're writing. It may just be a guess but since I am doing one very similar for my GCSE.... 
Anyway the way I did this was

```
Dictionary = {}
with open('clues.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        Dictionary[l[0]] = l[1]
```

Comment: -1: It doesn't work. There is a space between values. File in Python doesn't autosplit lines on whitespace. You could [use `line.split()` explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156659/4279)

Comment: It does work. It is working in my program. It is the accepted answer so clearly it works in the poster's program. Maybe your file is different to mine and theirs? I know for a fact that his will work since his 'clues.txt' is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: let's consider the first line: `l = 'j ^\n'` in this case: `l[0] == 'j' and l[1] = ' '`. You do *not* want `l[1]` to be space that is why `key, val = l.split()` is useful: `key = 'j'` and `val = '^'`. Notice: `l[1] != val`. Your code does not produce `{'d': '!', 'j': '^', 'm': '+'}` dictionary i.e., *it does not work*.

Comment: The example the OP has given here may not work and I stand corrected. However for this specific question I happen to know exactly what the text file he will be using is formatted like and so this code witll work for that. There are not supposed to be spaces between the two letters.

Comment: ["this specific question"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22156519/4279) **has** space between key and value. period.

Comment: This question has been resolved. I have accepted Harvey's answer and I can say that it works with my program.

Answer (score 3):

I did this:

```
Dictionary = {}

with open("File.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        Dictionary[key] = val
```

(So ... don't try to turn the key letters into integers) and got this:

```
In [8]: Dictionary
Out[8]: {'d': '!', 'j': '^', 'm': '+'}
```

Seems to work fine.

You were using `[int(key)]` but your keys are all letters and Python's [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) built-in expects a number. `int()` will take any number, even if that number is stored as a string and convert it to an integer. You don't need integers for your dictionary.

Comment: @Chopster0123 If the answers fixes your issue, you should accept it when the system allows you to(click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/235416) for a full explanation.